# Entity framework Mapping API referencing error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use third party package for Bulk insert in entity framework: [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef5)

Problem is that my project uses Entity Framework mapping 5.0.0.9 and when I run 3rd party package I get an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.MappingAPI,
>   Version=5.0.0.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ee2e825d201459e' or
>   one of its dependencies.

On packages page it says that all versions between 5.0.0.6 and 6.0.0.0 are supported. So I guess I should just somehow change the version it uses, but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a binding redirect to the web or app config file to tell the framework that when a lower version of the dependent assembly is required, it should load your desired version instead. 
It would be something like this:

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework.MappingAPI" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="7ee2e825d201459e" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.9" newVersion="5.0.0.9" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: I found the new ans here